# Using environment variable for accesslogvalve dir

Tags: tomcat, tomcat-valve

I want to populate "dir" in accesslogvalve from a value from setenv.bat.
Ex:

```
<Valve
className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
directory="${my.logs.dir}"
prefix="access_log"
fileDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd.HH"
suffix=".log"
pattern="%t %H cookie:%{SESSIONID}c request:%{SESSIONID}r  %m %U %s %q %r"/>
```

I have specified "my.logs.dir" in setenv.bat

`set my.logs.dir=C:\xyz\abc`

When I start the tomcat, I see a folder ${my.logs.dir} under tomcat installation.  The issue is that ${my.logs.dir} was not replaced by env variable when tomcat startsup. If I give hard coded value like  `dir="C:\xyz\abc"`, it works fine.

Could anyone guide me to replace ${my.logs.dir} with a value from environment at server startup time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think environment variables are available by default in Tomcat configuration files. System properties, however, are. So if you add your variable as a system property instead of an environment variable, it should work.

If you for some reason absolutely have to use environment variables, the Tomcat documentation has a reference to Property replacements in it's section about [System Properties](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html#Property_replacements) that can be set to customize Tomcat behaviour:

> org.apache.tomcat.util.digester. PROPERTY_SOURCE
>
> Set this to a fully qualified name of a class that implements org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.PropertySource. Required to have a public constructor with no arguments.
>
> Use this to add a property source, that will be invoked when ${parameter} denoted parameters are found in the XML files that Tomcat parses.

Comment: Thanks NilsH I will explore Propery_source option.